How do I draw text that's right aligned in Pygame?
I am making a Math-thingy that requires numbers to be drawn to the screen right aligned.
I'm using this function to draw text:
def drawText(text, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    screen.blit(img, (x, y))

How do I draw the text right aligned instead of left aligned?
I tried to use Python's .rjust() function for this, but I'm not using a monospaced font.
Is there anyway to possibly either use .rjust() to right align it or possibly something else?

The pygame.Rect object has a set of virtual attributes that can be used to define the position of surfaces and text. Align the text to its right by setting topright:
def drawText(text, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    rect = img.get_rect(topright = (x, y))
    screen.blit(img, rect)


Minimal example

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 32)
count = 0

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        
    count += 1
    text_surf = font.render(str(count), True, "black")
    rect = screen.get_rect().inflate(-110, -110)
    
    screen.fill("white")
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, "red", screen.get_rect().inflate(-100, -100), 5)
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(topleft = rect.topleft))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(midtop = rect.midtop))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(topright = rect.topright))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(midleft = rect.midleft))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(center = rect.center))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(midright = rect.midright))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(bottomleft = rect.bottomleft))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(midbottom = rect.midbottom))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(bottomright = rect.bottomright))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
exit()

